# gitignore rule on files in a folder also ignoring the folder

Tags: git, gitignore

This might just be me misunderstanding the git docs but this seems unexpected to me.

I have added two folders relative to my GIT_WORK_TREE folder (the base folder for my app):

```
public/javascripts/cached_files
public/stylesheets/cached_files
```

I want these folders to be in git, but i don't want the files in them to be in git, so i added these rules to `.gitignore`:

```
public/javascripts/cached_files/*
public/stylesheets/cached_files/*
```

It seems to be ignoring the folders: if i do `git status` then it doesn't show me any new files.  I'd expect it to show the folders but not the contents.

Can anyone explain this?

thanks, Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empty folders are ignored by git, you can get around this by adding a hidden file inside the folder called something like `.keep_in_git`

Comment: Ah - so "empty" means "having no files which aren't ignored by git", so even though there's stuff in there, because the stuff is ignored the folder is classed as empty and thus doesn't show up in `git status`.  Gotcha.  I don't think i can do your workaround though because the `.keep_in_git` file will be ignored by my `.gitignore` rule.

Comment: Or do i need to take the rules out, commit the folders with the file, them put the rules back?

Comment: You can still add the ignored file explicitly: git add -f

Comment: Thanks.  Which i should do AFTER deleting any files in it, as i just discovered :)

Comment: @MaxWilliams Note that git doesn't *ignore* empty folders, simplified git only handles files and the folder structure only gets build by the paths of those files. So git can not save an empty folder. If you want to learn more about this you can take a look at the [Git Objects](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) chapter of the gitpro book which makes it pretty obvious why git can't handle empty folders.

Comment: Traditionally, this file is often called `.gitkeep`, though there is no technical reason to use this name.